# Asynchronous timeouts with ChannelFuture

Tags: multithreading, netty, future

Netty framework uses a [ChannelFuture](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html) for performing asynchronous I/O operations.

For example, the following method call [Http2FrameWriter#writeHeaders](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/Http2FrameWriter.html#writeHeaders-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-int-io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Headers-int-short-boolean-int-boolean-io.netty.channel.ChannelPromise-) returns a ChannelFuture that would write the header on a given channel. These tasks are usually queued on the [Channel's IO Thread](https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#scheduling-an-arbitrary-task-to-be-run-by-an-io-thread).

```
ChannelFuture writeHeaders(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                           int streamId,
                           Http2Headers headers,
                           int streamDependency,
                           short weight,
                           boolean exclusive,
                           int padding,
                           boolean endStream,
                           ChannelPromise promise)
```

I have registered a ChannelListener to handle exceptions on failures as below but it does not cover any timeouts.

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = ctx.writeHeaders(
        ctx,
        streamId,
        headers,
        0,
        endOfStream,
        ctx.newPromise()
);

channelFuture.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            Throwable cause = future.cause();
            // Do some error handling
        }
    });
```

Previously, I have used Java 8's CompleteableFuture which allows one to specify asynchronous timeouts along with exception handling as described at [Asynchronous Timeouts with CompletableFuture](https://dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-timeouts).

Is it possible to do the same with ChannelFuture?

Answer (score 1):

You would just submit a task that is run after a specific timeout when the write is not done.

Something like this:

```
ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
if (!future.isDone()) {
    Future<?> scheduled = ctx.executor().schedule(() -> {
        if (!future.isDone()) {
            // Do something as the write did not complete yet.
        }

    }
    future.addListener(f -> {
        scheduled.cancel();
    })
}
```

Also check the `WriteTimeoutHandler` which does exactly this in a generic way.